# Short story on Mars with wind blown sand structures resembling chapels

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Story is on Mars.  Windblown sand structures at times resemble the chapel at U of Chicago where the narrator's love and her small dog died in a nuclear attack.  Interwoven at times with older images of a European chapel containing Robert and Elizabeth Barrett Browning and their small dog.  Narrator is accompanied by an empty spacesuit blown by the winds. Thought story was by Fritz Leiber with title about 'Change Winds' but no luck in finding it.

Comment: Fritz Leiber wrote one called 'when the changewinds blow' part of his change war collection. However Jack L Chalker wrote one with the exact same title

Answer (score 10):

You're very close, it's "[When the Change-Winds Blow](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57327)" by Leiber.

The original magazine publication cover showed the chapel on Mars, and the empty green spacesuit tumbling.

[image]